# How to optimize out the space a class reference member takes?

Tags: c++, optimization, reference

```
template<typename T>
struct UninitializedField
{
    T& X;
    inline UninitializedField( ) : X( *( T* )&DATA )
    {
    }
protected:
    char DATA[ sizeof( T ) ];
};

int main( )
{
    UninitializedField<List<int>> LetsTest;
    printf( "%u, %u\n", sizeof( LetsTest ), sizeof( List<int> ) );
}
```

I am trying to program a class that wraps an object without being automatically initialize\constructed.
But when I execute my program the output is:

```
8, 4
```

Is there a way to optimize out the dereference to get into the object in `X` and the space it takes?

Comment: You could make that a `union` and ensure that the constructor/destructor are evaluated at the right times. A different question is why you want to create an object that wraps an uninitialized member... two-phase construction is often better avoided. BTW, there is always the answer: *If you don't want the reference, just don't create it* (i.e. you could provide a member function that returns a reference but not store it)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I don't want to initialize it because it allocated on the heap in the start. I use list a lot in my program and most of the times it ain't needed. (But sometimes needed) about the member function, it takes a function to execute. My program is verb critical on performance. BTW how I can make it with the union? I get errors.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Tried function member but on release and it optimized it out.

Comment: Don't forget alignment. Right now your structure is only char-aligned, which may be a problem if T requires stricter alignment.

Comment: @RaymondChen The memory itself is aligned to bytes. Doesn't matter I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
struct UninitializedField {
    __inline UninitializedField( const T &t ) {
        *( ( T* )this ) = t;
    }
    __inline UninitializedField( bool Construct = false, bool Zero = true ) {
        if ( Zero )
            memset( this, 0, sizeof( *this ) );
        if ( Construct )
            *( ( T* )this ) = T( );
    }
    __inline T *operator->( ) {
        return ( T* )this;
    }
    __inline T &operator*( ) {
        return *( ( T* )this );
    }
protected:
    char DATA[ sizeof( T ) ];
};
```

There isn't any space taken, and with compiler-optimization on there's no call to function.